# "Read Data from Firebase", not working after update 2.8.1

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Solution**

Added code before return

```
 if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.red,
            )),
          );
        }
```

**important!**  -   **if (!snapshot.hasData)**

---

I try show data from FireBase, I have DB on Firestore.

I updated today Flutter (2.8.0 -> 2.8.1) , code worked before update

My code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class FireService extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FireServiceState createState() => _FireServiceState();
}

class _FireServiceState extends State<FireService> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('chats/uHdJ4WvHjvphsBUpb9yk/visits')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Visits'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _usersStream,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      data['company'],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      data['number_visit'].toString(),
                    ),
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.local_offer,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

After starting an error occurs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8wv4.jpg)

Please, write a new code so I understand the error. Thanks

UPD 1.

I tried an option

```
children: snapshot.data?.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
```

a new mistake - the whole block of code with a red line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8cGC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `snapshot.data!.docs.map` should use the nullish coalescing instead of the `!`.

The line should be:

```dart
snapshot.data?.docs.map
```

`data?.` will gracefully break if data is null

Comment: I tried an option, a new mistake - the whole block of code with a red line